# How to rewrite or compile my JS module to WASM?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to give my JavaScript library a boost by rewriting (or compiling) it in Web Assembly.
How would I do that?

Comment: Start by [reading the project page](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thank you Derek. However, it is missing the js->wasm compilation info. Also, I'm looking for wasm rather than asm.js

Comment: "*To build to wasm, use `emcc [..args..] -s WASM=1`*" - [Project page](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly)